# Get n data based on the same day (timestamp)

Tags: mysql, timestamp, date

I have this table "sensor" which has these fields :

- id (int,PK)
- timestamp (timestamp)
- latitude (varchar)
- longitude (varchar)
- data (float)

As in one query I want to get 5 rows that were on the same day. Please note that it's not current date and the data has lots of different dates. So, if they were on the same day I would like to get them..
I tried using INTERVAL but it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: What query have you tried so far ???

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM `sensor` 
WHERE `timestamp` >= INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 5

Comment: I just posted my answer. As for your query it should read : `SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE timestamp >= DATE(NOW()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;`

Comment: `INTERVAL` is an operator to add and subtract on `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` values

Comment: Once you see my examples, you use `LIMIT` against as you wish.

Comment: `VARCHAR` for numeric info (lat/lng)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want the see the number of sensor data point for the last week

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) dt,
    COUNT(1) datapoints
FROM sensor
WHERE
    timestamp >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

To see this month by day

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) dt,
    COUNT(1) datapoints
FROM sensor
WHERE
    timestamp >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-1) WEEK + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

To see this year by day

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) dt,
    COUNT(1) datapoints
FROM sensor
WHERE
    timestamp >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1)
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

To see this year by month

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp - INTERVAL (DAY(timestamp)-1) DAY) dt,
    COUNT(1) datapoints
FROM sensor
WHERE
    timestamp >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1)
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp - INTERVAL (DAY(timestamp)-1) DAY);
```

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` can be replaced by `CURDATE()`.  `+ INTERVAL 0 SECOND` probably does nothing useful and can be removed.